# Entry for the CC field goes into the To field

Tags: vba, outlook

My code looks like this:

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set myItem = Item
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim oAccount As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim oMail As MailItem
    Dim Recip As Outlook.Recipient

    Set oAccount = Application.ActiveExplorer
    MsgBox (oAccount.CurrentFolder.Store)

    If oAccount.CurrentFolder.Store = "1@2.com" Then
        MsgBox ("CC needs to be added")

        Set Recip = myItem.Recipients.Add("user@test.com")
        Recip.Type = olBCC
    Else
        MsgBox ("no need to add CC")
    End If
End Sub
```

The part responsible for adding user@test.com to the CC field is adding that address to the "To:" field instead.

Comment: If it is VBA use the vba tag.  VB.NET is something else

Answer (score 0):

i just had to add Recip.Resolve after Recip.Type = olCC. That solved the issue.